# Run content script on widget click in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I just finishing a chrome extension which add a content script on click on the browser button.
I'm looking for a same way to accomplish it with firefox, I find [PageMod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) but it seem to not work inside a onclick event into my widget.

Any suggestion to make this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you call "the browser button" is what Mozilla calls a [widget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/widget.html).  Activating a [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) doesn't require you to click anything, only to "attach" (open) a matching web page.

To interact with page content (a page's DOM) following the clicking of a widget, the value of the widget's `onClick` attribute should be an anonymous function of no arguments, in which a variable is set to the active tab's `attach` event:

```
var self=require("self");
var data = self.data;
var widget = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");


var erase = widget.Widget({
 id: "magated",
 label: "click this widget",
 content: "<div>?</div>",
 contentScriptWhen: "start",
 contentScriptUrl: data.url("cs.js"),
 onClick:function () {
  worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptWhen: "start",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("cs.js")],
  });
  worker.port.emit("dothing", tabs.activeTab.url);
 },
});
```

in cs.js one might find the following:

```
self.port.on("dothing", function (url) {
  var bigUrl = document.createElement("h1");
  bigUrl.textContent = url;
  document.body.insertBefore(bigUrl, document.body.firstElementChild);
});
```